# How to use getline and strtok together in C?

Tags: c

this is my first time asking a question here so I hope I am doing it correctly! For a while now I have been trying to get getline and strtok to work together in order to read text from a file and break it into words. Essentially the text file input is an essay and I want to manipulate each word individually later on. The problem I am getting is a constant "assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast"; I have tried everything I can think of. This is my code as of right now:

```
int nbytes = 100;
char *buffer;
char *token;
buffer = (char *) malloc(nbytes + 1);
getline(&buffer,&nbytes,file);
token = strtok(&buffer, " ");
```

I feel like it's problem something really simple that I am overlooking. That you for reading and your help!

Comment: Note that if you have a new enough libc to have `getline`, you probably also have `strsep` which is the new-n-improved `strtok`.

Comment: also don't cast the return type of `malloc`. This could hide exactly the same problem of not including the correct header file that declares it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standard C (on its own) doesn't define anything named `getline`. To read a line from a file you normally use `fgets`.

The error you describe *sounds* like you don't have a prototype for `strtok` in scope, so the compiler is treating it as if it returned the default type (int). You'd normally eliminate that by adding `#include <string.h>` somewhere close to the top of the file.

Comment: you were right I didn't have <string.h>. That helped to fix the problem; thank you!

Comment: While c does not, the 2008 version of POSIX includes `getline` (with the GNU semantics) in `stdio.h`, though not every system supports that yet. And you want `getline` if you have to beg borrow or steal to get it, because it will manage `buffer` to insure that it can get the whole line.

Comment: @dmckee: well, not really -- long before POSIX included `getline`, a guy named Martin Maney wrote something he called `xgetline` that did roughly the same thing. Glancing at my copy, I apparently modified it somewhat in 1994 -- but to make a long story short, I had that covered long before POSIX did...

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you want `&buffer` in your `strtok()` call.  Also, you're not including `string.h`, which is why you're getting the warning "assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast".  Without a correct prototype for `strtok()` available, the compiler is assuming that it returns `int`.  The conversion of that `int` to `char *` to make the assignment to `token` is the assignment it's complaining about.

Edit - thanks to @dmckee for the signature of `getline()`.

Comment: That along with including <string.h> helped fix the problem. Thank you so much!

Comment: `getline(char ** lineptr, size_t * n, FILE * stream)`

Answer (score 0):

one more error is using &buffer instead of buffer.

&buffer is pointer to pointer to char, but you need pointer to char.